# What causes duplicate messages to be repulled when using commitSync?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a consumer set up that manually commits offsets. Events are in the millions to low billions. I'm committing offsets if and only if processing was successful within the consumer batch being processed. However, we're noticing that even with `commitSync` being called successfully, we have hundreds of thousands of duplicates. We will commitSync and just repull the same exact data in the consumer on the next poll from the topic. Why would this happen?

Comment: Is there anything suspicous in the logs, like a CommitFailedException? Which kafka-clients and broker versions are you using? Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan - Kindly ensure that you have set below property for Consumer

```java
props.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "false");
```

Even if above is not giving you the desired result due to huge load, kindly commit the current offset with below constructor so that you will not get the offset in next Poll.

```java
public void commitSync(java.util.Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> offsets)
```

Follow API at
[commitSync](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync--)